# Billing Agreement not showing in customer account page

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, billing

I am trying to display a customer's billing agreement information inside the customer account page but for some reason it won't show the billing agreement just the default "There are no billing agreements yet."

I can use the billing agreement information (saved credit card) when I checkout so I know it has been created I simply need to show it inside the customer account page.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
                    <li class="home">
                            <a title="" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home')  ?></a>
                                        <span>&gt; </span>
                        </li>
                         <li class="youraccount">
                            <a title="" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Your Account')  ?></a>
                                        <span>&gt; </span>
                        </li>
                    <li class="payment">
                               <strong><?php echo $this->__('Payment')  ?></strong>

                        </li>

      </ul>
</div>
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Payment') ?></h1>
</div>
 <?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
<?php //echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<div class="my-account">
    <div class="tabcontainer">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#" rel="#one"><?php echo $this->__('Your Billing Addresses') ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="#two"><?php echo $this->__('Your Billing Agreements') ?></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="one" class="cont-sec" style="display:block">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('account_address'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="cont-sec">
       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('account_payment'); ?>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.tabcontainer ul li').click(function() {
            jQuery('.tabcontainer ul li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('.cont-sec').hide();
            var curRel =  jQuery('a', jQuery(this)).attr('rel');
            jQuery(curRel).show();
            jQuery(this).addClass('active'); 
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

I am using the childHtml method to call the sales/billing_agreements template file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('account_payment'); ?>
```

But something isn't right and I'm not sure what it is???

Please help somebody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to invoke the correct block inside my custom.xml file

```
 <reference name="content">
    <block type="sales/billing_agreements" name="customer.account.billing.agreement" as="billing_agreements" template="accounttab/payment.phtml" >
 </reference>
```

Comment: where do you put this?